# (Android) Bluetooth LE will be interrupted intermittently

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnect, period

[image]

The period was set to 0.1 seconds.
but As shown in the screenshot, this data is abnormal.
It takes 0.4 seconds once every 10 seconds.
The phenomenon occurs regularly every 10 seconds.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried this on another device and confirmed the same form of delay? Also can you post your bluetooth polling logic (or whatever may be applicable for the bluetooth code) ?

Comment: JoxTraex // thank you!